# Integral of iid random variables

Tags: integration, random-variables

Say I have a measure $\mu^{i}$ where $i \in I \equiv[0,1]$ and $\int_{I} d \mu^{i}=1$, and a random variable $\varepsilon^{i}$ which is iid. I want to calculate $\Phi=\left[\int_{I}\left(\varepsilon^{i}\right)^{1-1 / \sigma} d \mu^{i}\right]^{\sigma}$. The note I read says "Suppose that $\log \varepsilon \sim N\left(-v_{\varepsilon} / 2, v_{\varepsilon}\right)$, then $\Phi=\exp \left(\sigma\left(\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}\right)\left(\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}-1\right) \frac{v_{\varepsilon}}{2}\right)=\exp \left(\frac{1-\sigma}{\sigma} \frac{v_{\varepsilon}}{2}\right)$".

I cannot get around how is this calculated and why $\Phi$ is not also a random variable but a real number.